# How to navigate to iOS Native Add Contact Page in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, native, contacts

I've been looking on how to get this done:
I have a contact list with an "add contact" button. My goal is to open the native add contact page (mainly for iOS) when I click on that button.

I know how to call the method from flutter, but I don't know how to do the calling add contact screen with swift.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured things out.
If someone needs it here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Contacts
import ContactsUI

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      
      let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
      setUpMethodChannels(controller: controller)
      

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    
    private func setUpMethodChannels(controller: FlutterViewController) {
        
        let contactChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.flutter.contact_list/addContact",
                                                  binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        contactChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
              (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
             
            guard call.method == "AddContact" else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                return
            }
            
            let con = CNContact()
            let mainVC = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: con)
            mainVC.delegate = controller
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
}

extension FlutterViewController : CNContactViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    public func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) {
            viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }    
}
```